# Add two items in DataGrid column in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I want to have a `CheckBox` and a `TextBlock` together in a column of `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="one">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1"></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And I want to bind data from database to this column:
My data in database field is like that: `"0-Hello"` or `"1-Bye"`

If field was `"0-hello"` then `checkBox1` should be unchecked and `textBlock1` should be equal to `"hello"`.

If field was `"1-bye"` then `checkBox1` should be checked and `textBlock1` should be equal to `"hello"`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Datatrigger to set the checkbox and a Converter to get the substring that you wan't to view

```
<DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="one" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding YourProperty,Converter={StaticResource GetSubStringConverter}}"></TextBlock>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" >
                                <CheckBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty[0]}" Value="0">
                                                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </CheckBox.Style>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

the converter will simply extract the text to display

```
 public class GetSubStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return value.ToString().Substring(2);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to create a Value converter for your data :

```
public class StringBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    if(value.ToString() == "0-Hello")
                       return false;
                    else if(value.ToString() == "1-Bye")
                        return true;
                    return false;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    if(value is bool)
                    {
                            if((bool)value == true)
                                    return "1-Bye";
                            else
                                    return "0-Hello";
                    }
                    return "no";
            }
    }
```

And call it in your XAML :

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >
     <DataGrid.Resources>
         <local:StringBooleanConverter x:Key="StringBooleanConverter" />
     </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="one">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1"></TextBlock>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" IsCheked="{Binding Path=YourBooleanProperty, Converter={StaticResource StringBooleanConverter}}"></CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Note: don't foget to decalre local namespace in your Window.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.DataBinding.ConverterSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourConveterNameSpace"
        >
    //...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom IValueConverter to parse the string into the text you want, or a boolean:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="one">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding DataString, Converter={StaticResource DataToTextConverter}}"  />
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox1" Text="{Binding DataString, Converter={StaticResource DataToBooleanConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And in your resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DataToTextConverter x:Key="DataToTextConverter"/>
    <local:DataToBooleanConverter x:Key="DataToBooleanConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And code behind:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(String))]
public class NotificationSeverityColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //strip the first two characters
        return parsedString;
    }
}
```